# how to properly and efficiently load new records using Eloquent

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I have a `Status` Model in which each of its instances can have many child statuses/comments. I'm able to collect these comments by way of this relationship function:

```
public function comments() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Status', 'parent_id');
}
```

Now on the initial load of the web page, each status is shown with a maximum of 4 comments ( the last 4 recent comments). What I want to do now is:

upon selection of a "View More Comments" button, make an AJAX request to an endpoint to grab the previous 20 latest comments and render them to the page. I've been able to set up my AJAX just fine and even the rendering but I'm grabbing all the comments, even the initial comments already rendered, rather than a chunk of only the next set of 20.

Should I use Eloquents [Chunk Method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-chunk),[Take Method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-take), Or [Splice Method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-splice)? or a combination of another set of methods?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever seems best to you and whatever solves your problem. But be sure not to get out from the domain of laravel. But in my opinion, here the concept of [Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination) can come in handy. Its super easy and comes with a lot of methods.